# Correctly affect value of stuct pointer

Tags: c

I have the current structures

```
struct  Protocol__ChecksumTable
{
   ProtobufCMessage base;
   uint32_t tableindex;
   size_t n_entry;
   Protocol__ChecksumEntry **entry;
};

struct  Protocol__ChecksumEntry
{
   ProtobufCMessage base;
   uint32_t index;
   uint32_t value;
};
```

now I declared a `Protocol__ChecksumTable*` structure filled by a function which return a `Protocol__ChecksumTable*`

```
Protocol__ChecksumTable *
   protocol__checksum_tables_response__unpack(void);

...

Protocol__ChecksumTable * checksumTablesResponse;
checksumTablesResponse = protocol__checksum_tables_response__unpack();
```

---

And now I want to modify the field entry on `Protocol__ChecksumEntry` like this:

```
checksumTablesResponse->entry[0]->value = value;
```

the returned value is not null, as I can log it correctly:

```
for (index = 0; index < checksumTablesResponse->n_entry; index ++) {
   LOG("checksumTablesResponse->entry[index]->value);
}
```

7 values will be displayed:

```
3054867360
3054867360
379899191
4128997118
3185498542
1736976844
2545413521
```

But then the program crashes!
What's wrong?

Comment: **1.** `checksumTablesResponse` is a pointer, is it not `NULL`? **2.** `(...)->entry` is an array, does it have at least size of 1? **3.** `(...)->entry[0]` is a pointer, is it not `NULL`?

Comment: are (not) you missing couple of `typedef`s, at least?

Comment: @AndreKampling i updated the question

Comment: What are the contents of `checksumTablesResponse` and `checksumTablesResponse->entry[0]` when you step to your function in GDB?

Comment: "7 values dispalyed" Maybe `(...)->entry[7]` is `NULL` but `(..)->n_entry` is larger than 7?

Comment: did you allocate the memory for  the `entry *` values?

Comment: @PeterJ I dont think so, the program is working for display, it's not mine, it display properly, so entries has memeory allocated I guesss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you have UBs as you do not allocate any memory, and you random results as UB means - *everything may happen*

```
Protocol__ChecksumTable *checksumTablesResponse;
```

then alloc the memory for the structure and some inits

```
checksumTablesResponse = malloc(sizeof Protocol__ChecksumTable);
checksumTablesResponse -> entry = NULL;
checksumTablesResponse -> n_entry = 0;
```

when you add the *entry*

```
checksumTablesResponse -> entry = realloc(checksumTablesResponse -> entry, sizeof(Protocol__ChecksumEntry *) * (checksumTablesResponse -> n_entry  + 1);
```

then you can add the entry

```
checksumTablesResponse -> entry[checksumTablesResponse -> n_entry++] = .......
```